# random string, shuffle string from an array

Tags: php

Does anyone here knows how to shuffle string (random output string) from an array like, I have this array (refer below)

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");

function random_string(){
    //here a function to randomize or shuffle the items from the $cars array
    return $random_string;
}

echo random_string()
```

any help, suggestions, recommendations, clues, ideas is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/array_rand) ? - `echo $cars[array_rand($cars, 1)];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the php rand() method.

```
$random_string = $car[rand(0,count($car)-1)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$random_string = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
shuffle($random_string);
print_r($random_string);
```

you can try this one